# epub library for python

Tags: python-2.7, epub, epub3

Getting this error while using epub python package or you can say epub library for python , wondering what to do about it. please help..

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:/4th semester/3", line 4, in <module>
book=epub.open_epub('d:\welcome.epub')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\epub\__init__.py", line 43, in open_epub
return EpubFile(filename, mode)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\epub\__init__.py", line 82, in __init__
self._init_read()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\epub\__init__.py", line 143, in _init_read
self.toc = ncx.parse_toc(self.read_item(item_toc))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\epub\__init__.py", line 276, in read_item
return self.read(os.path.join(self.content_path, path))
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 931, in read
return self.open(name, "r", pwd).read()
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 957, in open
zinfo = self.getinfo(name)
File "C:\Python27\lib\zipfile.py", line 905, in getinfo
```

'There is no item named %r in the archive' % name)
    KeyError: "There is no item named u'OEBPS\\toc.ncx' in the archive"`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

From your question I presume you are using `Python-Epub` library from here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/epub/0.5.1 and you are running in Windows.

It helps to know that [EPUB](http://idpf.org/epub)s are essentially zip files. A typical bug in Python EPUB-handling libraries is attempting to build paths **inside** zip archive with `os.path.join` as if it were regular file system. On Windows `os.path.join` squeezes Windows file path separators (i.e., `\\`) that are not recognized by `zipfile` module.

This is a bug in `epub` library (which should be reported) yet you can easily get a work-around as following:

1. Determine where your `epub` sources are located:

   `python -c "import epub; print epub.__file__"`
2. Add the following function to `epub` sources:

   `def zip_path_join(a, *p):
       for b in p:
           a += '/' + b
       return a`
3. Search `epub` sources for `os.path.join` and replace it with `zip_path_join`
4. Enjoy!

Comment: I've reported the bug on bitbucket at https://bitbucket.org/exirel/epub/issue/5/invalid-zip-path

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the report of the issue. This is... well... shame on me, I should have fixed that a long time ago.

So, I've pushed a new version 0.5.2, and you can upgrade your version and see if it works as you expect (it should, yet I didn't run unit-test on any Windows env).

PS: I won't say "I got a life and stuff happen", but... yeah, that's just it...